# Inserting geolocation meta data from images uploaded in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, upload, geolocation

We are doing a wordpress blog where we are having people uploading images and video from locations and writing about them.

It would be great to use the geo tagged info that is stored on most devices when taking photos and use this data to build a map with images.

However, looking at the meta info for images in the relevant fields in the database does not have this information in it. Size, apperture, etc yes, geo location info no.

Does anyone know how I can enable this so that when an image is uploaded into a post it stores this somewhere?

Thanks for your help

Paddy

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geotag/)? One of its features is to "Read the geotags from the exif header of the photos of your post and show them".